# Relaxed continuous mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ be sequences of random elements taking values in some normed space $S$ and defined on the same probability space. Next, assume that
$$
X_{n} = O_{p}(1),
$$
i.e. $X_{n}$ is stochastically bounded and
$$
Y_{n} \overset{a.s.}{\to} a,
$$
where $a$ is a constant element from $S$.

Next, let $f:S\times S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. The question is the following hold
$$
f(X_{n}, Y_{n}) = O_{p}(1).
$$

**Remark.** By $O_{p}(1)$ I mean that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a finite $M$ and $N$ such that
$$
P(|X_{n}|>M)<\varepsilon, \, \forall \, n>N.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if the normed space in question is finite dimensional and complete.  Otherwise, it may not be.

To start with, assume $S$ is finite dimensional and complete.  In particular, bounded subsets of $S$ are compact.

Since $Y_{n} \to a$ almost surely, it converges to $a$ in probability.  In particular, there is an $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
P(\|Y_{n} - a\| > 1) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3} \quad \text{if} \, \, n \geq N_{1}.
\end{equation*}

Choose $M > 0$ and $N_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
P(\|X_{n}\| > M) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3} \quad \text{if} \, \, n \geq N_{2}.
\end{equation*}

$f$ is continuous so there is a $K > 0$ such that $|f(x,y)| \leq K$ in the compact set $\bar{B}(0,M) \times [a - 1, a + 1]$, where $\bar{B}(0,M) = \{x \in S \, \mid \, \|x\| \leq M\}$. Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
P(|f(X_{n},Y_{n})| > K) \leq P(\|Y_{n} - a\| > 1) + P(\|X_{n}\| > M) \leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3} \quad \text{if} \, \, n \geq \max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}.
\end{equation*}

If $S$ is not complete or not finite dimensional, the argument above fails because the result is no longer true.

In the non-complete case, we could use $S = \mathbb{Q}$ and let $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ with $x_{n} \to \pi$.  Define $f : \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x - \pi}$.  If we take the deterministic random variables $Y_{n} \equiv a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X_{n} \equiv x_{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(X_{n},Y_{n}) = \frac{1}{x_{n} - \pi}$ surely and this is not stochastically bounded.

If $S$ is not finite dimensional, then closed balls are no longer compact in the norm topology.  Consequently, we can find an unbounded continuous function $g : \bar{B}(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$.  Choose $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \bar{B}(0,1)$ such that $|g(x_{n})| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  As before, use deterministic sequences $Y_{n} \equiv a$ and $X_{n} \equiv x_{n}$ with $f(x,y) = g(x)$ to get that $f(X_{n},Y_{n})$ is not bounded.

Comment: why did you choose $1$ in $P(|Y_{n} - a| > 1) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$?

Comment: also, note, the question is not for random numbers. It is about sequence taking values in some normed space.

Comment: @LrM, I edited the post.  (I chose one in the bound for $\|Y_{n} - a\|$ because any constant would work, and "to an analyst, all constants equal one.")